# Php simple html dom remove div with specific class

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

I am using the code bellow to get some content. My problem is that i don't know how to avoid/bypass/remove a specific div.

html Structure:

```
<div class="post-single-content box mark-links">
<div class="sharebar-wrap">dfdfdfd</div>
</div>
```

And i an using the code bellow to get the content:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links]') as $table)
{
$arr44[]=  $table->innertext ;
}
```

How can avoid or remove or bypass to grab the div with class sharebar-wrap?
I don't need it!

Cheers!!

Comment: According to your code i think you are not going to get div with class name sharebar-wrap? Are you getting this also with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use jQuery as *Héctor E* mentioned, otherwise you can use raw javascript :

```
document.querySelector('.sharebar-wrap').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

With javascript:

```
var aux = document.getElementByClass('sharebar-wrap');
aux.parentNode.removeChild(aux);
```

With jQuery:
 `$( ".sharebar-wrap" ).remove()`